# Strong Induction on Tribanocci Numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Define Tribanocci Numbers as
\begin{align*}
T(0) & = 0\\
T(1) & = 1\\
T(2) & = 2\\
T(n+3) & = T(n+2) + T(n+1) + T(n)
\end{align*}
Prove by strong induction that $T(n) \leq 2^{n-1}$ for all natural numbers $n$.

I have set up my Strong Inductive Hypothesis - Suppose that for all $j < k$, $T(j) \leq 2^{j-1}$.

I know I need to show the claim will hold for $k$ but am not sure how to start?

Comment: Hi ! Welcome to Stackexchange. This looks like a homework question. If you want someone to read your post and perhaps help you, say what you've done so far, where you'e stuck and eventually what are your ideas to solve it. And learn Tex formatting !

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Check that $T(1) = 1 \leq 2^{1-1}$ is true. Assume $T(k) \leq 2^{k-1}$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n-1$, then: $T(n) = T(n-1)+T(n-2)+T(n-3) \leq 2^{n-2}+2^{n-3}+2^{n-4} = \dfrac{7\cdot 2^n}{16}< \dfrac{2^n}{2}= 2^{n-1}.$

Comment: To use the inductive hypothesis on three consecutive values, shouldn't the base case consist of verification for three consecutive initial values?  [In fact here, the base case does hold for $n=0,1,2$.]